# Writing tests for a Symfony2 service that uses the database

Tags: symfony

I'm creating a small bundle for Symfony2, which does nothing more than provide a service; it can be called to insert a line into the database, containing a few parameters:

```
class AuditLogService {

 private $em;

 public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
 {
  $this->em = $em;
 }  

 public function log($type, $channel, $message) {
  $log = new AuditLog();
  $log->setType($type);
  $log->setChannel($channel);
  $log->setMessage($message);
  $this->em->persist($log);
  $this->em->flush();
 }
}
```

Now I need to write a test for it, so basically here are the steps I'm assuming I should take:

1. write a test that gets logger service, but uses a mock `entityManager` instead?
2. call function on that logger which uses the mocked em
3. try to fetch it back from the mocked em, using the parameters I used in step 2
4. assert if I find a result or not

I'm pretty sure that in theory these are the correct steps, but can anyone point me into the right direction as to how to actually do it?

I have this:

```
public function testServiceLoaded()
    {
       $this->assertEquals(get_class($this->container->get('bbit_audit_log.service')), 'BBIT\AuditLogBundle\Services\AuditLogService');
    }
```

This comes back with the following error:

> "bbit_audit_log.service" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.entity_manager"

It seems like my container does not contain the `entitymanager`?

Answer (score 1):

In unit test skip 3 and 4. It's not responsibility of AuditLogService to save in the database (but to call em). 3 and 4 should be tested by functional test.